# Native JavaScript Method that Mimics jQuery's .click()

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I recently realized that in learning to write JavaScript using jQuery, I learned JS syntax, but I never really learned JS. So the project here is to mimic jQuery methods using only native JavaScript.

I started with a function of the global window object which returns a set of methods that I would commonly use:

```
window.iq = (function(){
    return {

    id: function(id) {
            return document.getElementById(id);
    },

    // Several other similar methods
})();
```

So, now I can invoke that method like so:

```
iq.id('elementID') //and so forth
```

I'm having trouble writing a method that mimics jQuery's `.click()`. I can attach a click handler to a set of elements like so:

```
[].forEach.call(iq.selAll('a'), function(el) { // selAll is the short version of document.querySelectorAll()
    el.addEventListener('click', function(){
        // do stuff
    });
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to write a method that does that, so that each time I want to fire a click event on an element or set of elements, I can just write:

```
iq.click('element', function(){
    // do stuff
});
```

Here is my non-working attempt at this:

```
click: function(el) {
    return [].forEach.call(iq.selAll(el), function(el) {
        el.addEventListener('click');
    });
}
```

As always, I very much appreciate any advice or guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is missing the second parameter to the `click` method, which is the actual handler function:

```
click: function(el, handler) {
    return [].forEach.call(iq.selAll(el), function(el) {
        el.addEventListener('click', handler, false);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So the handler is the function when I call `iq.click('a', function(){`? Is the handler always going to be a function? Also, according to MDN, the third parameter is `useCapture`, which defaults to false. Even after reading the docs I'm not entirely sure what that may be used for :-0

Comment: Yes, the handler is always a function. Though you don't need to pass a function expression (the `function(){…}` thing), you can also pass variables or anything else that produces a function (`handler` in my answer is a variable). The `useCapture` flag is only interesting when it's set to `true`, read [about the DOM event dispatch phases](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#dom-event-architecture)